# can't read else part

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my divs to check/uncheck.
But, else part can't read my code (undefined)
Plz help me...

(First time click is fine
second time click is undefined)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Blocking.css";

const Blocking = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([false, false, false, false, false]);

  const onCheck = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute("name"));
    if (checked[e.currentTarget.getAttribute("name")] === false) {
      e.target.style.background = "aquamarine";
      setChecked(!checked[e.target.getAttribute("name")]);
      console.log("if " + checked[e.target.getAttribute("name")]);
    } else {
      e.target.style.background = "white";
      setChecked(!checked[e.target.getAttribute("name")]);
      console.log("else " + checked[e.target.getAttribute("name")]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="items" name="0" onClick={onCheck}>
        1
      </div>
      <div className="items" name="1" onClick={onCheck}>
        2
      </div>
      <div className="items" name="2" onClick={onCheck}>
        3
      </div>
      <div className="items" name="3" onClick={onCheck}>
        4
      </div>
      <div className="items" name="4" onClick={onCheck}>
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blocking;
```

Below code block is console.log in chrome)

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Blocking.jsx:9 2
Blocking.jsx:14 if false
Blocking.jsx:9 2
Blocking.jsx:18 else undefined
```

1st i click any blocks then, print fine.
2nd i click any blocks then, print undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in:

`setChecked(!checked[e.target.getAttribute("name")]);`

The "checked" array is being replaced by a boolean.

You could do it as:

```
let newChecked = [...checked];                     //Destructure
let index = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("name")   //Get index
newChecked[index] = !checked[index]                //Toggle check

setChecked(newChecked)
```

Comment: I clicked but message pops up like this - (Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.)

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You are mutating your `checked` state array. `setChecked(!checked[e.target.getAttribute("name")]);` mutates the state to a single boolean, so subsequent `checked[e.currentTarget.getAttribute("name")]` conditional tests will likely *always* be falsey.

You are also directly manipulating the DOM. This is an anti-pattern in React.

You need to shallow copy the *entire* array and update the specific index. Use the state value to derive the background color.

```
const onCheck = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const index = Number(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("name"));
  setChecked(checked => checked.map((val, i) => i === index ? !val : val));
};

return (
  <div className="container">
    <div
      className="items"
      style={{ background: checked[0] ? 'white' : 'aquamarine' }}
      name="0"
      onClick={onCheck}
    >
      1
    </div>
    ...etc
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit cant-read-else-part]

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I tried that code but, every blocks' colors change to aquamarine + nothing happens

Comment: @hyeonyohwan Indices are type "number" whereas `name` is type "string" so you need to convert the found `index` value to a number type. I updated my answer and added a *working* codesandbox link. Please take another look.